# How can I handle Uncaught TypeError of a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to open a tab multiple times using the JavaScript code given below..

```js
function webAssign() {
  let i;
  let myWin;
  for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log(i);
      
    myWin = window.open("index.html");
    myWin.close();
  }
}
```

After running this code, it throws the error given below..

`Uncaught TypeError: myWin is null`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check if the variable is not `null` before calling `.close()` on it? Or are you asking _why_ it is `null`?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking why it is null?

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN's page for `window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

> **Return value**
>
> A WindowProxy object, which is basically a thin wrapper for the Window object representing the newly created window, and has all its features available. **If the window couldn't be opened, the returned value is instead `null`.**

*(my emphasis)*

There are contexts (environments where your code may be running) that can't open windows, or can't open windows to certain origins. In those contexts, `window.open` returns `null`. For example, the Stack Snippets feature here on SO disallows `window.open`:

```js
function webAssign() {
  let i;
  let myWin;
  for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log(i);
      
    myWin = window.open("index.html");
    myWin.close();
  }
}
webAssign();
```

Running that on Chrome gives the error (in the web console):

> Blocked opening 'https://stacksnippets.net/index.html' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

---

But separately from that, opening and immediately closing windows in a tight loop doesn't really make any sense.